# Detect NetStream events with AS3 Video Object (not component)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv, flvplayback

I have created a FLV video player using the AS3 flash.media.Video object (not the FLV playback component) and I am trying to listen for meta events and Cue Points embedded in the FLV video but I am not receiving any when I trace the movie. The cue points are not being created dynamically, they are in the FLV video.

Video embed code:

```
    // Initialize net stream
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect (null); // Not using a media server.
ns = new NetStream(nc);
// Add video to stage
vid = new Video(456,675);
addChild (vid);
// Add callback method for listening on
// NetStream meta data
client = new Object();
ns.client = client;
client.onMetaData = this.nsMetaDataCallback;
client.onCuePoint = this.onCuePoint; 
// Play video
vid.attachNetStream ( ns );
ns.play ("flv/00_010.flv");
```

callback handlers in the same class as the above code:

```
public function onCuePoint(info:Object):void { 
trace("cuePoint: time = " + info.time + " name = " + info.name + " type = " + info.type); 
if (ns) ns.pause();
}

public function nsMetaDataCallback (mdata:Object):void {
trace (mdata.duration);
}
```

Is there anything I am missing have wrong to capture events from my net stream?

Comment: I feel your code is alright, but there might be some problem with the `flv` file itself. Try with another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty much exactly the same code that I have working. The only thing I can think of is the creation of the Video object itself. I have mine declared as a property of the class itself, although I can't really think why having the declaration in the function call would matter as it's still added to the stage.

I trust you see the video ok?

One rather silly guess would be to try switch the client assignment and attachNetStream calls if the attachNetStream call does something to the NetStream.

```
vid.attachNetStream ( ns )
ns.client = client;
client.onMetaData = this.nsMetaDataCallback;
client.onCuePoint = this.onCuePoint;
```